# What are the advantages of using Functional Data Analysis (FDA) over traditional Time Series or Stochastic Process approaches?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, finance, time-varying-covariate, functional-data-analysis

In the case where the curves (functions) are defined on a time interval.